# Sublime SFTP file upload issue

Tags: sublimetext

I am having directory issues when using sublime sftp to upload files. Currently am using ftp type, and the issue is this:

My local and remote folders match, but when I take a file from the local side that is say 3 directories deep and modify/upload, it's putting the file to the root folder and not the directory location.

Any ideas are appreciated.

NOt sure if this helps, but

Uploading "/Volumes/--/Dropbox/ItsJustFood/web/wp-content/themes/justfood/library/css/style.css" to "/library/css/style.css" ..... success

looks like it's only going two directories up when it should be going to the root?

Comment: cd into the correct remote directory first?

Comment: yeah, I checked using Dreamweaver just to make sure.

Comment: Create folder struct in remote side first

Answer (score -1):

Turns out you have to make sure the .json file is also in the root folder of your remote copy.